# Zend Form text element with array notation issue

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using Zend_Form and have got stuck in a situation. I have an array of some values like below :

```
$feeTypes = array(1,2,3,4);
```

and want to create 6 text elements in zend form that should be rendered like following:

```
<input type="text" name="class_fee_type[1]" />
<input type="text" name="class_fee_type[2]" />
<input type="text" name="class_fee_type[3]" />
<input type="text" name="class_fee_type[4]" />
```

I tried the following code but don't know that how to associate the above $feeType array.

```
$class_fee_type = $this->CreateElement('text','class_fee_type')
                                ->setRequired(false)
                                ->setAllowEmpty(false)
                                ->setIsArray(true)
                                ->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false)
                                ->setDecorators(array( array('ViewHelper')
        ));
```

I'm not using any subform in this form. This is absolutely simple zend form.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm talking from ZF1 point of view:

It seems like there is no standard way of doing what you need. So I would recommend write your own form element and element view helper for that. And passing your indexes array as options to element.

Note: to use setRegisterInArrayValidator - your Zend form element should extend Zend_Form_Element_Multi.